# Adding a custom symbol in excel's currency format

Tags: excel

I want to add a new currency symbol to excel's currency type menu. It currently supporting all fiat money and bitcoin, with its own symbol. Is there a way to create a custom symbol from a existing unicode character?

e.g. ****Ξ for ETH****

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the Currency format. You can use a custom format and use any character in there. Start with a currency format that you want to use, apply it to a cell and close the dialog box.

[image]

Next, open the Format Cells dialog and change to Custom format. Here you can simply replace the currency symbol with one of your choice:

[image]